# SugarCRM: Displaying error with photo in listview

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to display an image in the listview, so I created a non-db field which is getting filled with an img tag by a process record hook. The code of the logic hook is the following:

```
$bean->picture_c = "<img src='index.php?entryPoint=download&id={$c->picture}&type=SugarFieldImage&isTempFile=1' style='height: 70px; width: 55px; '>";
```

It works fine but when the user does a simple or extended search it won't display any data until the user hides the column for the picture. Sugar throws no error it only says "no data/no records found" but after hiding the column and refreshing the site, all records of the previous search are displayed correctly and if I'm changing the photo column to visible the records are extended with the photo in the listview.

Do you have any hints why the search displays no data?

Comment: Is there anything in the SugarCRM logs? I suspect sugar might be adding picture_c to the query.

Comment: Sugar adds ORDER BY picture_c to the query. Is there a way to change the query so it won't order by picture_c?

Comment: Try adding `'sortable' => false,` to the entry in the `listviewdefs.php`. You may need to clear cookies or entries in the users preference table to make sugar forget that `picture_c` should be sorted.

Comment: ah...simply remove the photo field from the sort by setting in the extended search because it's selected on default because it's the first column in the listview...
thanks for your help!